# How do I set the default icon set and wallpaper for new users?

Tags: icons, users, desktop-background, default

I would like to change the default icon set and wallpaper so when a new user is created they have them automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new dummy user, modify its settings to your liking and cherry-pick the changes from .config and .gconf, place them into `/etc/skel`. Keep the directory structure intact, e.g. copy:
`/home/dummyuser/.gconf/desktop/gnome/background/%gconf.xml`
to:
`/etc/skel/.gconf/desktop/gnome/background/%gconf.xml`

Note:

- Install `gconf-editor` and try to locate the settings that interest you. The tree structure maps directly to the files involved.
- Be proficient in XML-editing, e.g. a syntax-highlighting editor like geany may show you common typos (In case you want to impose only a subset of the keys in the XML-file, you need to delete the remainder correctly)
- Less is better, too much branding may cause eye-fatigue ;)

Comment: Changes here only seem to affect an account on second logon..?

Answer (score 3):

While I haven't tested this with more recent versions of Ubuntu, I believe that [Sabayon](http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon/) is what you are looking for.

It allows you to tweak all kinds of defaults: panels, background, templates, etc. It is often paired with [Pessulus](http://live.gnome.org/Pessulus) for restricting access to certain features, though is probably more than you need.

**Update**:
It does work in 11.10, and it has been renamed to "User Profile Editor".

Answer (score 1):

You could edit `/usr/share/gconf/defaults/16_ubuntu-artwork` and `/usr/share/gconf/defaults/16_ubuntu-wallpapers` for setting the default theme/icon set and wallpaper respectively. The file structure is pretty simple. For example, to change the default wallpaper you have to edit the line:

`/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png"`

to

`/desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "/PATH/TO/CUSTOM_WALLPAPER"`

Make sure that the custom wallpaper can be read by everyone and be extra cautious when editing these files as you may damage your system.

Comment: Changing 
"/desktop/gnome/interface/icon_theme     Eustasy" doesn't seem to have effected it.